# JQuery phototag: few remove actions - last not working with additional actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jquery phototag plugin by Karl Mendes. It's made to tag persons on pictures.
When tag is added - person is appended in an inline list(ul li), comma automatically added to previous li:

```
var createTagItemForList = function( tagJSON, image ){
    if ($('.photoTag-taglist').html().length>0) {
        $('.photoTag-taglist li').last().append(', ');
    };
    var item = $('<li></li>');
    if(tagJSON.url){
        var link = $('<a href="'+ tagJSON.url +'">'+ tagJSON.text +'</a>');
        item.append(link);
    }else{
        item.append(tagJSON.text);
    }
    if(tagJSON.isDeleteEnable){
        var deleteLink = $('<a id="'+ options.imageWrapBox.tagListRemoveItemIdPrefix + tagJSON.id +'" class="'+ options.tag.deleteLinkCssClass +'" href="#'+ tagJSON.id +'">'+ options.literals.removeTag +'</a>');
        registerEventsForDeleteLink(deleteLink,image);
        item.append(' (');
        item.append(deleteLink);
        item.append(')');
    }
    return item;
}
```

But each person have (x) link to delete it and i have to delete comma in previous li when last is deleted.
When I delete items like 1, 2, 3 - everything goes right.
But when I delete it like 2, 3, 1 - i can delete 2, anyway can't delete 3 and anyway can delete 1.
Source code for delete function:

```
var registerEventsForDeleteLink = function( link, image ){
    link.click(
        function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var tagId = link.attr('href').substring(1);
            var parameters = getParametersForImage(image);
            parameters[options.tag.tagIdParameter] = tagId;
            $.getJSON(options.deleteTagsUrl,parameters,
                function( data ){
                    if(!data.result)
                        manageError(data);
                }
                        );
            //next line removes "li" so all i say next was tried instead of this line
            $('#' + options.tag.deleteLinkIdPrefix + tagId).parent().remove();

            $('#' + options.imageWrapBox.deleteLinkIdPrefix + tagId).click();
            return false;
        }
    );
};
```

I've tried several ways:

1. right in link.click checking if the element is last in ul list and removing comma in last item after remove(via .replace())
2. just remove comma in last "li" in link.click after all actions
3. add on/bind(remove) for list and do "remove comma actions" there.

Anyway if I delete items like 2,3,1 - I can't delete 3. Click event is just not working for it(tested by alert inside function).

With source code everything goes good - I can delete items in any order.

Can you tell me how to delete comma in previous item if last is deleted?

I found solution! Add comma not just like text but like this:

```
<span class="comma">, </span>
```

Then remove it via .remove();
I used to delete comma via:

```
string=$('ul li').last().html().replace(/,/g, '');
string=$('ul li').last().html(string);
```

which probably deleted click event for delete tag link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution! Add comma not just like text but like this:

```
<span class="comma">, </span>
```

Then remove it via .remove(); I used to delete comma via:

```
string=$('ul li').last().html().replace(/,/g, '');
string=$('ul li').last().html(string);
```

which probably deleted click event for delete tag link.